# React.JS: Detect if keyboard input is from a barcode scanner

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, barcode-scanner

I am working on a problem where we need to detect if a user used a barcode scanner to scan something into an input box, or they just typed in values using a regular keyboard. Based on each scenario, we want to have different callbacks that handle the user input.

I am porting over a codebase that previously leveraged jQuery detect barcodes using this library: https://github.com/escaleno-ltda/jQuery-Scanner-Detection.

I am now re-writing this code in React.JS but I am stuck here as there are no available libraries on React.JS for this.

Is it possible to import that code inside my React.JS (create-react-app) project?
I did yarn install jQuery-Scanner-Detection and tried to import it, but I get this issue:
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
(This is in the dependency file, not my project. I figured it would not be easy to modify a dependency.)

Another way: Is it possible to implement the logic natively in React.JS? It basically detects the speed of user input to the keyboard, and if it is fast enough then we consider it a barcode scan. Otherwise we consider it a regular keystroke.

Comment: Cant you just react on keyDown, then its user input?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that library, it tries to check for three things

- (optional) A specific keycode that the scanner emmits when the button is pressed
- (optional) A character keycode that the scanner emits at the end of a barcode
- The timing between characters

Given that, with `React`, you have can subscribe to DOM events and implement the same logic, the answer to the second question is, yes, you can create a React component.

Comment: This makes sense to be, but I am not enough of an expert in Javascript to fully understand how this works... Is there a straightforward way to wrap it without too much effort?

Comment: What you're asking is for someone else to do the work you're being paid for. If you want to message me, we can talk rates - I do project work from the UK.